# Get most recent year of records on year and month field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table such as this:

```
Id | Year | Month
1  | 2018 | 1
2  | 2018 | 2
3  | 2018 | 3
```

I need to select the most recent 12 months of ids and here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT TOP 12 [Id],
YEAR([DateReported]) AS [Year], MONTH([DateReported]) AS [Month]
FROM (
    SELECT [Id], CAST(CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/' + CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/1' AS DATETIME) AS DateReported
    FROM [MyTable]
) T
ORDER BY T.[DateReported] DESC
```

However, I'm doing far too much casting, is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. First combine two columns (year/month) into a date and then extract year/month from it?

Comment: This should return the same result: `select top 12 * from MyTable order by [year] desc, [month] desc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your Select returns the correct result there's no need for any kind of calculation, simply order using:

```
select top 12 Id, [year], [month]
from MyTable 
order by [year] desc, [month] desc
```

Comment: I knew I was overthinking it, now that I look at it, its rather awkward i didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select t.*
from t
where year * 12 + month >= year(getdate()) * 12 + month(getdate()) * 12 - 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would sort by month (descending), then I would get first 12 rows, as in:

```
select top 12 id
from my_table
order by year * 12 + month desc
```

Comment: Should be `year * 12 + month`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't want the most recent 12, you want the ones from the most recent 12 months (aka a year). You don't need to do any casting at all....

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1), year int, month int);

insert into @t(year, month)
values (2017,11)
  ,(2017,11)
  ,(2017,12)
  ,(2017,12)
  ,(2018,1)
  ,(2018,2)
  ,(2018,1)

select *
from @t t
where format(t.year , '0000')+'-' +format(t.month, '00') >= format(dateadd(year, -1, getdate()), 'yyyy-MM')
```